# Instruments not using latest build

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, instruments

Building for instruments already takes an inordinate amount of time - about 5 minutes. And then I'm trying to investigate where a memory leak is coming from, so I'm commenting out various things then testing, again each test taking 5 minutes to build.

So then it's after an hour or so, and much frustration at the issue coming and going, seemingly without pattern, that I see something which I commented out, appear on screen. So I change the title bar text, build, and start in Instruments. Just as I suspected, the title text hasn't changed. So here's my process:

1. Build for Profiling.
2. Profile.
3. Instruments and the simulator both open, or come to the foreground ready to test.
4. I press the record button.

This does **not** make it test the latest version, but actually, just a recent version. I suspect the issue comes when you don't fully, entirely, close Instruments. While it does build, and puts Instruments in front of you after pressing Profile, it doesn't use that build.

This is incredibly frustrating. Is there a pattern to this? Something, I'm somehow doing wrong? This has wasted a lot of time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem: the instruments app doesn't use the latest build even if I clean the project and open instruments again. @Andrew did you find any solutions to this issue? I'm using the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with Xcode 6.3.1...

I've managed to overcome it by doing the following but it's cumbersome:

1. Close the Instruments app.
2. Clean the project.
3. Run the project as usual on the simulator and stop it after the project is launched.
4. Profile the project again.

If anyone knows why this is happening and have a better solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem persists for me in Xcode 6.4.  I find that

1. Quite Instruments & Simulator
2. Rebuild & Run in Xcode
3. Quit Simulator
4. Press Cmd+I to profile from Xcode

seems to work for me and is a lot quicker than doing a clean.